# Change the behaviour of a LocatorPane

Tags: graphics, dynamic, eventhandler, locator

Normally, `LocatorPane` detects any single click as in the following example:

```
    DynamicModule[{pt = {1, 1}/2}, 
     {LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], Graphics[{Gray, Disk[]}]], Dynamic[pt]}]
```

My  goal is to redefine the behaviour of `LocatorPane` to detect only double clicks (i.e., the value of `pt` is returned only when the user double-clicks in the `LocatorPane`)

I tried the following definition, but with no success!

```
doubleclickPane[pt_, back_, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  DynamicModule[{ptt = pt},
    Deploy @ EventHandler[
      LocatorPane[Dynamic@ptt, back, ,Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[LocatorPane]]]],
      {"MouseDown" :> (
        ptt = MousePosition["Graphics"]; 
        If[Mod[CurrentValue["MouseClickCount"], 2] == 0, pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]]
      )}
    ]
  ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Your code seems to intend to do something a little different than what I understood from the question - so I hope this is right. :)

Fixing the code require two changes,

1. remove `Deploy` -- it makes the `EventHandler` inoperative; and
2. put `Dynamic` around the argument `pt` -- one of the important attributes of `Dynamic` is that it is `HoldFirst`, which allows the symbol to be passed to a control instead of merely its value (otherwise the symbol could not be updated).

Code -- *Edit: Updated to handle options*

```
doubleclickPane[Dynamic[pt_], back_, opts : OptionsPattern[LocatorPane]] := 
 DynamicModule[{ptt = pt}, 
  EventHandler[LocatorPane[Dynamic@ptt, back, opts],
   {"MouseDown" :> (ptt = MousePosition["Graphics"];
      If[Mod[CurrentValue["MouseClickCount"], 2] == 0, 
       pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]])}]]
```

In this form a single click moves the `Locator` (i.e. updates the local variable `ptt`).  A double-click changes the argument `pt`.  Since `ptt` appears outside the `If` statement, I assumed that was the desired behavior.

Example:  I double-clicked near `{0.5, 0.5}` and then single-clicked near `{-0.35, 0.2}`.

```
myPt = {0, 0};
doubleclickPane[Dynamic[myPt], 
 Graphics[Circle[], PlotRange -> 1, Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Follow-up:* If I had passed `myPt` instead of `Dynamic[myPt]` to `doubleClickPane` (and there was no `Dynamic` in the definition), only the value `{0, 0}` would be passed.  The control `doubleClickPane` would not be able to change the variable `myPt`, because that symbol never got passed to the code.  As it is, `pt` is the symbol `myPt` in the function call and the important piece of code

```
pt = MousePosition["Graphics"]
```

is really

```
myPt = MousePosition["Graphics"]]
```

Without `Dynamic`, this line becomes the invalid statement

```
{0, 0} = MousePosition["Graphics"]]
```

Comment: Your code works very good!I can not understand why you  use  Dynamic[pt_] instead of pt_ in your definition of doubleclickPane! Also why Deploy@ is nouse here?

Comment: @kornaros  I updated the answer to address your questions.

Comment: I tried your code without  Dynamic over pt_ and worked. Maybe I am wrong...Anyway thank you for your code&comments.

Comment: I tried some LocatorPane's options like Appearance ->"String" in doubleclickPane but without any success! Any ideas?

Comment: @kornaros For the options, I simplified the code and it worked (see above).  I don't know what you mean when you say it "worked" without `Dynamic`.  I removed `Dynamic` from both `Dynamic[pt_]` and `Dynamic[myPt]`, and `myPt` was always `{0, 0}`.  It never changed.  In other words, double-clicks had no effect.